# Find a ring with exactly 2009 ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Find a ring with exactly 2009 ideals.

No more information is provided, is there anything to be noted about the number '2009'. Some hint towards the direction of the answer would suffice.

Comment: @Magdiragdag could you explain a little more may be with an example.

Comment: (possibly correct) hint: Try $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$ for some choice of $k$?

Comment: @Timkinsella could you explain the motivation behind this example or point me towards some relevant theory

Comment: My suggestion is a cyclic group. Theres a subgroup of a cyclic group for each divisor of the order.  So there are $k$ subgroups (maybe I'm off by 1), but for quotient rings of the integers, additive subgroups are the same as ideals.

Comment: @Timkinsella excellent hint...thanks